# Iterating through a list in another list in groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to iterate over users list in groups list and if users list has the group(from group list) I need remove that from users list. I tried the following but its not working

```
def groupsList = entity.companyContainer.groups
groupsList.each { g ->
    g.users.each { u ->
       if( u.groups.find( g ) ) {
           u.groups.remove( g )
           entityService.update( u )  
       }
    }
    entityService.delete(g)
}
```

Exception:

```
ERROR | com.core.common.controller.impl.BaseMultiActionController | groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: 
    com.core.configuration.persistence.ListWithPersistentSetPropertyAccessor$ListWit‌​hPersistentSet.find()
    is applicable for argument types: (com.core.security.model.impl.Group) values: [LFO Super Users_Lawfirm]
 Possible solutions: find(groovy.lang.Closure),
                     find(groovy.lang.Closure),
                     min(),
                     min(groovy.lang.Closure),
                     min(java.util.Comparator),
                     size()
```

Comment: Why isn't it working?

Comment: Well then, sounds like the variable `u` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry copied incorrect stacktrace earlier, here is the correct one

Comment: ERROR | com.core.common.controller.impl.BaseMultiActionController |  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.core.configuration.persistence.ListWithPersistentSetPropertyAccessor$ListWithPersistentSet.find() is applicable for argument types: (com.core.security.model.impl.Group) values: [LFO Super Users_Lawfirm]
Possible solutions: find(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure), min(), min(groovy.lang.Closure), min(java.util.Comparator), size()

Comment: That implies that there's no method named `find` on `groups` that takes a `g` type.  What kind of object is `groups`?

Comment: I just changed if condition to  if(u.groups.find(it.id=g.id)) now its giving me different exception.  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: it for class: DeleteInvalidLawfirmOrClientCompanies

Comment: I don't know enough about groovy or your context to help you on that one.  Seems like you don't understand fundamental groovy language syntax though.  I'd read up more on groovy to fix this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41063/discussion-between-ranpaul-and-tietyt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not clear about the full context of the logic but you can get what you need using `find{}` as a closure operation as below:

```
def groupsList = entity.companyContainer.groups

groupsList.each{ g ->
   g.users.each {u ->
     if(u.groups.find{it.id == g.id}) {
        u.groups.remove(g)
        entityService.update(u)
     }
   }
   entityService.delete(g)
}
```

Comment: It going to work kind of the same way but in this context better fits method _any_ instead of _find_.